# Load balancing tick

Tags: ubuntu, power-management, kernel, powertop

After Ubuntu upgrade (some time ago, from rather ancient version), my Lenovo S10 netbook fan does not stop.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 10.10
Release:    10.10
Codename:   maverick

$ uname -a
Linux agladysh-s10 2.6.35-23-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 24 10:18:49 UTC 2010 i686 GNU/Linux
```

PowerTop reports high number of `[kernel scheduler] Load balancing tick` wakeups.

I remember reading somewhere that this is a known issue in recent kernels.

Any advice?

```
     PowerTOP version 1.13      (C) 2007 Intel Corporation                      

Cn                Avg residency       P-states (frequencies)
C0 (cpu running)        ( 2.7%)         1.60 Ghz     2.4%
polling           0.0ms ( 0.0%)         1333 Mhz     0.0%
C1 mwait         23.6ms (41.5%)         1067 Mhz     0.0%
C2 mwait          1.5ms ( 7.5%)          800 Mhz    97.6%
C4 mwait          1.4ms (48.3%)


Wakeups-from-idle per second : 403.7    interval: 1.2s                          
no ACPI power usage estimate available

Top causes for wakeups:
  32.1% ( 70.0)   [kernel scheduler] Load balancing tick
  17.0% ( 37.0)   [ehci_hcd:usb1, uhci_hcd:usb2] 
  11.5% ( 25.0)   USB device  1-5 : USB2.0-CRW (Generic)
  10.1% ( 22.0)   [acpi] 



 Q - Quit   R - Refresh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by upgrading to [Ubuntu 11+](http://www.ubuntu.com/download)